# Scanner expects more input than is needed

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm having an issue with a piece of my code that is meant to validate that user input is an integer and between the numbers 1-6.

The issue is that when I add the validation the scanner waits for input three times before it continues. It functions normally if I don't include the validation code. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
int level;
boolean good = false;
double physAct;
System.out.print("On a scale of 1 to 6, how active\ndo you consider yourself?\n1 = lazy, 6 = pro athlete: ");
System.out.flush();
while (!good){
    if (!in.hasNextInt()){
        in.next();
        System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter a whole\nnumber between 1 and 6: ");
    } else if ((in.nextInt() < 0) || (in.nextInt() > 7)){
        in.next();
        System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter a whole\nnumber between 1 and 6: ");
    } else {
        good = true;
    }
}
level = in.nextInt();
switch(level){
    case 1:
    physAct = 1.2;
        break;
```

After this the switch goes on and is used for some other operations.

Comment: "*when I add the validation the scanner waits for input three times*" how many times you use `next...` method? What do you think happens when you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop should read the input once and remember it as mentioned. Otherwise each call to `in.nextInt()` will block until you enter another integer. Keeping close to your same code you need to do the following.

```
while (!good){
    if (!in.hasNextInt()){
        in.next();
        System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter a whole\nnumber between 1 and 6: ");
    } else {
        level = in.nextInt();
        if (level < 0 || level > 6) {
            System.out.print("Sorry, you must enter a whole\nnumber between 1 and 6: ");
        } else {
            good = true;
        }
    }
}
```

remove the `level = in.nextInt();` after the loop since you already read in level.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your tests `(in.nextInt() < 0) || (in.nextInt() > 7)` both call nextInt().  You need to call it once, save the result and check the value on that.

```
int value = in.nextInt();
...
...(value < 0) || value > 7)
```